# Implementing a keyboard hook under windows produces massive bugs

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook

I tried to implement a basic hook under windows.
While it technically works (my handle gets called) it produces massive bugs, that i do not know how to fix.
When I run the programm and try to write something in the firefox.exe searchbar or the explorer.exe addres bar the programs crash.

That is the code i currently tried. I stripped everything unnecessary but it still doesnt work

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>


int main (int argc, char** argv){
  HINSTANCE dll = NULL;
  HOOKPROC proc = NULL;
  HHOOK hook = NULL;

  MSG msg;
  BOOL b_ret = FALSE;

  dll = LoadLibraryA("hookdll.dll");
  if (dll == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  proc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "KeyboardHook");
  if (proc == NULL) {
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, proc, dll, 0);
  if (hook == NULL) {
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WH_KEYBOARD, WM_KEYLAST) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
  FreeLibrary(dll);

  return 0;
}
```

And in the DLL:

hooks.h

```
#ifndef __LOG_DLL_HOOKS_H__
#define __LOG_DLL_HOOKS_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHook(
  _In_ int    code,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam);

#endif // !__LOG_DLL_HOOKS_H__
```

hooks.cc

```
#include "Hooks.h" 

extern "C" LRESULT CALLBACK  KeyboardHook(
  _In_ int    code,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam) {

  if (code == HC_ACTION) {

  }
  return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

As you can see it barely does anything.
I worked with the official windows docs and did everything the right way (or so i thought)
The only thing that could make a difference is the return value of KeyboardHook, but
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85) states that:

> If code is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
>
> If code is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns;

I read that as: "Return CallNextHookEx either way", which i did.

Thanks for any answeres

Comment: Why are you calling `LoadLibraryA` directly? You probably should be using `LoadLibraryExW `.

Comment: @Dai <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya>

>LoadLibrary can be used to load a library module into the address space of the process and return a handle that can be used in GetProcAddress to get the address of a DLL function.

Thats not part of my problem

Comment: @Dai there is nothing wrong with using `LoadLibraryA()` in this code (though `LoadLibraryW` would be better). The only reason to use `LoadLibraryExW()` instead would be if you want to utilize the extra search path flags to control where the DLL is looked for. That can be mitigated by simply using an absolute path instead of a relative path

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters, why are you using a *keyboard* function for a *window procedure* hook? I think you meant to use `WH_KEYBOARD` instead of `WH_CALLWNDPROC` when calling `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Also, your `GetMessage()` call is wrong, because `WH_KEYBOARD` is not a message identifier. You would need to use `WM_KEYFIRST` instead, to match your use of `WM_KEYLAST` (since you are clearly only interested in dispatching keyboard messages).

However, you are setting the `dwThreadId` parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` to 0, which means you are hooking not just your own thread but all threads of all processes globally.  A `WH_KEYBOARD` hook runs in the context of the thread that installs it, which means internally the OS will have to delegate the hooked keyboard messages of those other threads to your thread, and it does that by sending messages to your thread.  But, your message loop is not going to be processing any of those messages because it is filtering for only keyboard messages (of which it will never receive, since your thread has no UI of its own).

With all of that said, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>


int main (){
  HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibraryA("hookdll.dll");
  if (dll == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  HOOKPROC proc = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "KeyboardHook");
  if (proc == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return 1;
  }

  HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, proc, dll, 0);
  if (hook == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "WinAPI Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return 1;
  }

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
  FreeLibrary(dll);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As i said to the flags: "Yeah my bad. I played around with the flags a bit after it didnt work. The problem orginally occured with the correct values set"

Thanks for your response! Sadly the changes didn't solve the problem